# Shopify embed code renders not where it should

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, shopify, codeigniter-3

I have a website which features shopify embed buy  buttons. The site is Chandrikaglobal.com. It is built using bootstrap 3, with a shop section, which has 3 columns and it currently renders 10 products. They all render  in the col and row that they are intended to be in. These products have been active for over 3 years. Recently I tried adding a 12th product and it renders at he bottom of the page totally out of the shop section and row and column it is supposed to be in. The placement of the product is done via a php loop so it is automated, and there have been no changes in css or Javascript.

To debug, I went as far as removing all products and just trying to show this new product and the result is the same - rendering out of its section. I took it a step further and I took one of the existing products and replaced the relevant id's with the new products' id's yielding the same result. If I revert to that existing product's id it renders fine. The only thing that has changed is the shopify store used to be shopify lite and is now shopify basic.

Below is the code:

```
<?php
$this->load->view('components/global/header');
$max_description_chars = 80;
?>
<section class="slider" id="gallery">
    <h5 class="hide">Dummy Heading for w3 compliance</h5>
    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                <img data-src="application/images/carousel/carousell-1.jpg" alt="First slide" src="application/images/carousel/carousell-1.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img data-src="application/images/carousel/carousell-2.jpg" alt="Second slide" src="application/images/carousel/carousell-2.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img data-src="application/images/carousel/carousell-3.jpg" alt="Third slide" src="application/images/carousel/carousell-3.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <img data-src="application/images/carousel/carousell-4.jpg" alt="Fourth slide" src="application/images/carousel/carousell-4.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
        <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon carousel-control-left"></span></a>
        <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon carousel-control-right"></span></a>
    </div>
</section>
<div class="section_divider_announcements theme-text" id="announcements">
    <?php echo $announcements ?>
</div>
<section class="main__middle__container alt-back" id="home">
    <br>
    <h2 class="text-center">Home</h2>
    <div class="row about_heading__block text-left no-margin nothing">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $home_l ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $home_r ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="main__middle__container" id="about">
    <div class="section_divider"></div>
    <div class="row about_heading__block text-left no-margin nothing">
        <h2 class="text-center">About</h2>
        <div class="col-md-6 ">
            <?php echo $about_l1 ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $about_r1 ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row about_heading__block text-left no-margin nothing alt-back">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $about_l2 ?>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <?php echo $about_r2 ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>

<!-- End of slider section -->
<section class="main__middle__container" id="shop">
    <div class="section_divider"></div>
    <h2 class="text-center">Shop</h2>
    <?php
    if ($products !== 'No Prodcucts Available') {
        foreach ($products as $prod) {
            $this->load->view('products_description_modal', $prod);
        }
        $i = 0;
        $k = 0;
        $count = count($products);
        ?>
        <?php foreach ($products as $prod) { ?>
            <?php if ($i == 0) { ?>
                <div class="row about_heading__block text-left no-margin nothing">
            <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <div id="product-component-<?php echo $prod->component ?>">
                    <script>
                        <?php echo $prod->shopify_code ?>
                    </script>
                </div>
                <div class="text-left" style="padding-left:115px">
                    <br>
                    <a class="pointer" onclick="load_products_description_modal('<?php echo $prod->component ?>')">Details</a>
                    <br><br>
                </div>
            </div>
            <?php if ($i == 2 || $k == $count - 1) { ?>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php
            $i++;
            $k++;
            if ($i == 3) {
                $i = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</section>
<section class="main__middle__container alt-back" id="contact">
    <div class="section_divider"></div>
    <div class="row about_heading__block text-left no-margin nothing">
        <h3>Get in touch with us</h3>
        <hr>
        <br>
        <p id="feedback"></p>
        <form id="contact-form" name="contact-form" class="contact-form cmxform" autocomplete="off">
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="sr-only" for="name">Your Name: *</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name: *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                <label class="sr-only" for="email">Email: *</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email: *">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="subject">Subject:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="subject" placeholder="Subject:">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="message" name="message" rows="5" placeholder="Message: *"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="g-recaptcha hide" data-sitekey="6Lf6vK4ZAAAAAIiYmHoCXTIeTSfMQ1u78LCkf3uV" data-callback="recaptchaCallback"></div>
            <p id="capthca-error" class="hide error">Please verify you are not a robot</p>
            <div class="form-group">
                <br>
                <input id="submit-contact-form" type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit">
                <p id="email-success" class="hide">Thank you for your email. We will get back to you shortly.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="alert alert-success hide" id="msgContact">
                <strong>Success!</strong> Your message has been received. We will get back to you soon.
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</section>
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>

<?php
$data = array(
    'js' => array(
        'js1' => 'backToTop.js',
        'js2' => 'home.js',
    ),
    'street_address' => $street_address,
    'phone' => $phone,
);
$this->load->view('components/global/footer', $data);
?>
```

Comment: I think you need to share the code as well for better understanding. So anyone checks and delivers an answer according to the code.

Comment: The code seems fine, you need to share the steps on how you add the product, you said you delete all products and still this product is out of its place. so might be an issue with a particular product.

Comment: I am suspecting it is something to do with upgrading from shopify lite to shopify basic.  I have no insight how the shopify iframe works, I was hoping somebody has experience in this

Comment: As for the steps you ask for the shopify code is entered into a dB and rendered as shown in the code above.  The only difference for each shopify item is its component-id

Comment: I think nothing is related to Shopify plan, ping me from my profile link, I will check and help you

Comment: The problem has been fixed.  Not sure what Shopify did but it works now, Thanks Onkar for your help.